# How to use dart to compile a binary executable that ubuntu7 could use?

Tags: dart, compilation, static

I have a dart software `main.dart`:

```dart
main() {
  print("hello world");
  return null;
}
```

I did a compile with this command:

```bash
dart compile exe main.dart -o main.run
```

After I got `main.run`, I run it with `./main.run`.

It is working in ubuntu14 to ubuntu22.04, but it is not working in ubuntu12 and lower, for example, ubuntu7.

I heard that if you compile a software with full_static feature, it could get running in anywhere.

How can I do it with dart? My dear friends.

[image]